# Perl script to ONLY download certain URLs (https://...)

Tags: perl, lwp

following is working: but now I am trying to download a file from a website which needs authentication (and perhaps save a cookie, which expires in 24 hrs) to access content.

how to provide this authentication to the website? If an UN-authenticated user access the URL(or website) s/he is re-directed to the authentication page, where you have to put userid and password and press enter(login button). after authentication control goes back to the URL you originally asked automatically.

here is what i have so far, which is working for non-auth needing websites:

```
    #!/usr/bin/perl
    use strict;
    use warnings;
    use LWP;
    use Data::Dumper;

    my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new;
    my $agent = "my-lwp agent";
    $ua->agent($agent);
    $ENV{HTTPS_PROXY} = 'http://myproxy:8080';

    my $req = HTTP::Request->new(GET => 'https://mail.yahoo.com');
    $req->content_type('text/html');
    $req->protocol('HTTP/1.0');

    my $response = $ua->request($req);
     if ($response->is_success) {
         print "1 success\n";
     }
     else {
        print "1 error\n";
     }
    print Dumper $response;
```

Now I need to download this file from URL: https://myurl.com/file.doc
which needs authentication: username/password.

Adding problem definition: here is how to goes with a normal browser in my situation:...

1. post your url in browser: https://myurl/files/file.doc
2. you get a logon page (URL still looking same)
3. enter field names:  username/password
4. press 'ok' button  (field name btnSubmit)

after successfull login:

you get new page:   https://newurl/pagSuccess/

you have to click 'ok' on this page (to go back to where you wanted to go...)

then you get a browser dialog: where you have to:

> select (radio button) 'Save File'
>   press ok
>
> you are done!!! file saved locally.

Answer (score 5):

I would recommend using something such as [Mechanize](http://search.cpan.org/dist/WWW-Mechanize/lib/WWW/Mechanize.pm) to take care of this. It will handle the session cookies for you, and provides useful tools to identify and fill the forms for logging in.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the [`credentials` method for your `LWP::UserAgent`](http://p3rl.org/LWP%3a%3aUserAgent#ua-credentials-netloc-realm-) object.

Comment: it does not do form based authentication i think.